# Decorators are not valid here error after typescript(4.9.5) and angular upgrade (16.2.12)

Tags: typescript, decorator, typescript-decorator, angular16

I have upgraded my project to typescript 4.9.5.After that I am facing error 'Decorators are not valid here' at @Inject .For example in the below code,it is throwing the error mentioned at @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA).As far as what I know this is correct way to define the decorator in constuctors. It used to work fine before upgrade.
I am getting the error in almost all the constructors where i have used decorators like

```
constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ConfirmationDialogComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) data: any
)
```

```
export class CatalystModalComponent extends ConfirmDialog implements OnInit {
    @ContentChild(Body) body;
    constructor(
        el: ElementRef,
        renderer: Renderer2,
        confirmationService: CatalystConfirmationService,
        zone: NgZone,
        cd: ChangeDetectorRef,
        config: PrimeNGConfig,
        @Inject(DOCUMENT) document: Document       
    ) {
        super(el, renderer, confirmationService, zone, cd, config, document);
    }


}
```

I have tried all the approaches .As for as my understanding the syntax i am using is correct

Comment: Hi. You would probably need to be more specific than "error in almost all the constructors ". What error(s)? See [ask] for tips.

Comment: Hi , I have upgraded my project to typescript 4.9.3.After that I am facing error 'Decorators are not valid here' at @Inject .For example in the above examples ,it is throwing the error mentioned at @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA).As far as what i know this is correct way to define the decorator in constuctors. It used to work fine before upgrade

Comment: ok this sounds like relevant informaton and as such, please post it inside your question rather than in a comment